# Pagination with Custom Post Type not working on index.php: I get a 404

Tags: wp-query, pagination, 404-error

I've read many posts about the same problem but none seems to work for me.

I have a query for a custom post into the index.php. When I go to page 2 I get a 404 error. The same code works like a charm in any static page.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="inner-content" class="wrap clearfix">
                    <div id="main" class="clearfix main-index" role="main">
                        <h5 class="mini-title">Latest Works Added</h5>
                        <?php wp_reset_query();?> 
                        <?php 
                        // the query
                        $args = array('post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged);
                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                        ?>

                        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                        <!-- pagination here -->

                        <!-- the loop -->
                        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="fourcol home-article" role="article">
                                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><h3>Title</h3></td>
                                                <td><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><h3>Author</h3></td>
                                                <?php
                                                require_once'wp-content/themes/p-dpa/rdfa/lib/arc2/ARC2.php';
                                                include_once('wp-content/themes/p-dpa/rdfa/connect_to_store.php');

                                                // All Artists                      
                                                $query = '
                                                    PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> 
                                                    PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
                                                    SELECT distinct ?url ?name 
                                                    WHERE   {
                                                        <'.get_permalink().'> dcterms:creator ?url .
                                                        ?url foaf:name ?name
                                                    }
                                                ';
                                                $result = $store->query($query, 'rows');
                                                if (!empty($result)) {
                                                    echo '<td><h3>';
                                                    $names = array();
                                                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                                                        array_push($names, $row['name']);
                                                    }
                                                    echo implode(', ', $names);
                                                }
                                                echo '</h3></td>';
                                                ?>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                                            $first_image = catch_that_image();
                                            if ($first_image != '') { ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" class="img">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $first_image;?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </a>
                            </article>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>                      
                        <?php else:  ?>
                          <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="page-navigation">
                    <?php
                    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                     echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
                        'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
                        'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
                    ) );
                    ?>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that I can't explain: I had to change Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most = 1

Comment: this is really just masking the problem, not solving it. for an explanation of what's happening, see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126761/custom-wp-query-pagination-next-posts-link-or-wp-pagenavi-always-empty/126771#126771).