# Pagination always adding "Next" link when results come from Custom Post Type WP_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination

Or at least that's how it seems.

I have a page to which I pass several arguments to query post_meta for a custom field and I always get an extra "Next" link no matter the number of posts. If querying the same post type  without passing any variables to 'meta_query' (setting $female to null) in my WP_query, pagination works as expected.

I have looked at every link I can find about custom post type pagination (and there are a lot of them), have installed page-navi, and have scoured the codex, have disabled and reendabled my plugins. I'm feeling somewhat foolish so please be nice as I'm embarrassed I can't get this to work. Here's my stripped down code and any ideas would be appreciated.

The urls:

http://dev.huntingtonmedical.com/doctors/page/7/
http://dev.huntingtonmedical.com/doctors/page/5/?gender=female (the next link will take you to a blank page)

```
    get_header();

    $gender = $_GET['gender'];
    if ( $gender != 'female' ) unset( $gender );

    global $paged;

    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'doctors',
        'meta_key' => 'last_name',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'gender',
                'value' => $gender,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            ),
        )
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        $query->the_post(); 
        the_title();
        echo '<br>';

    }

    posts_nav_link(' | ',' Previous Page ',' Next Page ');
```

Comment: you're creating a new query in the template, but using the pagination from the main query, which runs before the template is loaded. have a look at [`pre_get_posts` in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and [on this site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=pre_get_posts).

Comment: I have been stumped by Wordpress exactly two times now and I still am. It makes no sense that this should work this way and seems like it should be considered a bug, but I will go back and continue trying to understand and fix this. Thanks for the comment and links though, for sure. Quickly though, is wrapping the query in a function and then calling that function with the pre_get_posts action  the simple answer?

Comment: it makes sense once you understand what's going on behind the scenes. [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126771/4771) may help shed some light on things. also have a look at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) to see the process WordPress goes thru for each request. Note where `posts_selection` is (the main query) and where `template_redirect` is (loading the template). `pre_get_posts` lets you modify the query *before* it happens - you don't perform your own query, you just set query vars.

Comment: So another hour has gone by and I'm feeling more foolish than before. I cannot find an example that makes sense. For instance, where does $qry come from in the answer on which you commented here? That is probably my missing link. Also, if I change the $args array into this $qry-> on this page [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102658/how-to-use-pre-get-posts)

Comment: Also, I tried your answer here [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52480/using-pre-get-posts-with-wp-query) and don't understand where the variables in your functions are coming from and nor do I know what "// do special stuff" might be. And man, I have spent like 8 hours trying to figure this out and am incredulous that I can't find an answer I can wrap my head around!

Comment: And finally, @Milo, I don't want any word done for me, but it should be somewhat clear that I kind of know what I'm doing - a simple example with the data I've got above would be unbelievably helpful. Would you mind as you seem to be the resident expert on this.

Comment: is `/doctors/` a page, or a post type archive?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12244/discussion-between-evan-rose-and-milo)

Comment: I don't think I can chat as I don't have the points. It's a post-type archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/doctors/` is a post type archive, so we can check if that query is being run in the `pre_get_posts` action via the [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type_Archive) `is_post_type_archive( 'doctors' )` and modify those queries accordingly.

WordPress passes the query object to the function by reference ( `$query` in this example ), so we can modify the query vars via the `set` method of the query object. This code would go in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function wpa_doctor_gender( $query ) {
    // if this is the main query on the doctors post type archive
    if ( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'doctors' )
        && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        // set query vars for all doctors queries
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'last_name' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

        // set meta_query if gender is female
        if ( isset( $_GET['gender'] )
            && 'female' == $_GET['gender'] ){
                $meta_query = array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'gender',
                        'value' => $_GET['gender'],
                        'compare' => 'IN'
                    )
                )
                $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_doctor_gender' );
```

Now in the template, we can get rid of all the custom query code and loop, and just run the vanilla loop to output posts:

```
while( have_posts() ) { 
    the_post(); 
    the_title();
    // etc..
}
```

Comment: First pass, this appears to be working! Sometimes when dealing with the guts, it's not clear what's been made available and what I need to do from scratch.

Comment: [This page in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview) is a good starting point to learn more about the query internals.

Comment: First pass, this appears to be working! Sometimes when dealing with the guts, it's not clear what's been made available and what I need to do from scratch. Also forgot you could pass $_GET parameters to functions! Thank you so much for your help and happy new year. (And believe me - I've read that page - I've read everything - just slow ;)